# Data Storage value in UI differs from a value returned by limits service

Tags: limits

I have found that Data Storage Values are different in the UI

[image]

and in the /services/data/v37.0/limits response

[image]

I know that storage values are calculated asynchronously but this is not the case as I'm sure there is nothing loading/loaded recently. Values differ in both Production and Sandboxes.
I'm building a page that displays those limits so I need this value to be accurate. Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: I tried to search more on this to know the difference between storage limits, but could not find anything. May be those extra MB's displayed using API are the hard limits after which Org will not allow user to add anything further. You can contact Salesforce Support to know more on this.

Comment: @Devendra thanks, looks like this is the only way.